# perf record blocks my linux machine

Tags: linux, perf

I'm trying to use `perf record` tool on my linux machine `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS` with kernel version `4.4.0-51-generic`. But after I run it my entire machine blocks and I must restart the computer. Other `perf` tools as `perf stat` for example work fine. The version of the `perf` is `4.4.30`. What can be the reason for such a behavior?

Comment: `perf stat` works fine, because it just reads/writes PMU counters, while `perf record` configures APIC to generate an interrupt on counter overflow. So there is something wrong in handling the interrupt. Do you have a kernel crash dump?

Comment: I have no kernel crash dump. I tried to enable kernel crash dump following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/kernel-crash-dump.html) instructions, but after executing `echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger` to test whether crash dump can be produced the system freezes again. After restarting there is no crash dump in `/var/crash`.

Comment: Crashing for me too with 4.4.0-45, wondering what happened ... I've used it successfully with 3.19.0-58 in the past, simple workaround might be to use an older kernel for profiling...